# On Random Rearrangements

Tags: real-analysis, probability, sequences-and-series

Let $\text{Sym}(\mathbb{N})$ denote the group of bijections $\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$. It is well-known that this has cardinality $\mathfrak{c}$. Suppose $a_n$ is a conditionally convergent series with $\sum a_n = L$. From a a result of Riemann, we have that for any real number $c$ there exists a $\pi \in \text{Sym}(\mathbb{N})$ such that $\sum a_{\pi(n)} = c$.

We want to consider random permutations $\pi(n)$, and study the convergence of $\sum a_{\pi(n)}$ from a probabilistic perspective. We can define a uniform probability measure on $\text{Sym}(\mathbb{N})$ by $P(E) := \mu(f(E))$ where $\mu$ is the Lebesgue measure and $f$ is a fixed bijection from $\text{Sym}(\mathbb{N})$ to $[0,1]$. Note: if this doesn't work, please feel free to suggest some other measures on $\text{Sym}(\mathbb{N})$.

What can we say about the expected value of $\sum a_{\pi(n)}$? Do we expect it to diverge? Converge to $L$? Does it depend on the sequence $a_n$? If this is the case, is there nevertheless something meaningful that can be said, specifically for "common" conditionally convergent series like $\sum n^{-1}(-1)^n$

Intuitively, I feel that we should expect it to diverge, because it's more likely for a given permutation to be "bad" than it is for it to be "good".

Comment: A more meaningful thing would be to take finite sums, take a random permutation in the standard sense (uniform distribution on the group), and ask what happens as the number of terms in the sum gets really large. I would be surprised if it hasn't been studied yet.

Comment: I'm not sure how you're going to get a uniform measure on $\text{Sym}(\mathbb{N})$ since there is no uniform measure on $\mathbb{N}$.  This master's thesis does consider the problem for various measures on $\text{Sym}(\mathbb{N})$ though: http://web.cs.elte.hu/szakdolg/gebaboy.pdf

Comment: @norfair I meant $\text{Sym}(\{1,2,\dots,n\})$, of course. +1 for the reference :-)